# Equivalent implementation of unique_ptr::reset for raw pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I'm trying to refactor a section of code into a separate object/file. To maintain the same behavior, my code needs to use pointers to key components in the original file, which are declared as unique_ptrs.

I was thinking to extract the raw pointers and pass them to my object since my portion isn't responsible for deleting any pointers. (I hope I'm understanding ownership semantics correctly, still relatively new to C++). The only caveat is that I need to replicate unique_ptr::reset's behavior. Will this code do the same thing reset does?

```
template <typename Type>
void reset(Type* &current_ptr){
       Type* old_ptr = current_ptr;
       current_ptr = new Type();
       if(old_ptr != null)
           delete old_ptr;
}
```

Comment: Don't think of the smart pointers a much as *pointers*, instead think of them in terms of resource ownership. Will a resource have only one owner at a time, then use `unique_ptr`; can a resource have multiple simultaneous owners, then use `shared_ptr`. Also, what do you think would happen if you get the raw pointer from the `unique_ptr`, and the `unique_ptr` object goes out of scope and deletes the memory pointed to? That will leave you with a stale pointer without your knowledge.

Comment: That's...definitely not what `reset()` does. What exactly are you trying to replicate? If your original code calls `reset()`, you are deleting pointers.

Comment: If your portion is not responsible for deleting pointers then your portion will not want to emulate a `std::unique_ptr::reset` because that deletes the poiter that the `std::unique_ptr` is managing. Using raw pointers is the right thing to do as long as you don't get into deleting/reassigning them. That should be the job of the owning smart-pointers.

Comment: Bottom line is you can't do the *reset()* without using the actual `std::unique_ptr`. You can't make it happen using the *raw pointer* that the `std::unique_ptr` is managing.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. The original code indeed calls `reset` and I was trying to avoid using `std::move` which seemed cumbersome since it required moving ~15 ptrs and then placing them back.

Comment: [OT]: it is safe to `delete nullptr`, so your check is unneeded.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call `reset` then you *are* in fact actually deleting pointers, and doing so outside the context of the `unique_ptr`'s destructor is a recipe asking for disaster (even if your code appears to work it may still be undefined behavior).

If in fact all you need is to dereference (primarily `*` and `->`) the `unique_ptr` then you should pass and use a *reference* to the object in your new code, making sure that the `unique_ptr` can't die while you're using the reference.

If you need to reassign or reset the smart pointer you'll need an alternate approach, but you didn't supply enough information in the question to help scope out such an alternate approach.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not what `reset()` does.

As pointed out in the comments, the features of smart pointers are about ownership, not pointers themselves. Ownership means responsibility, so if a `unique_ptr` owns an object, it is its "job" to delete it when the `unique_ptr` dies itself. `shared_ptr` are a little more complex, but they are also all about deleting the object "when the time comes", and taking that responsibility off of you, the programmer.

`unique_ptr`s are unique, that is, no two `unique_ptr`s should ever own the same object.

Now, the `reset()` method is a way of saying "hey, `unique_ptr`, I've got a new pointer for you to manage, so destroy the old one (if you had any) and take ownership of this new one that I'm giving you. From now on, this is the one you'll destroy when you die yourself."

This operation has no meaning with raw pointers, since they do not hold any ownership and won't kill themselves off at the right time or anything like that.

So, comparing that with your code, the similarity is that the old pointer is indeed deleted. But apart from the essence being missing (that is, the raw pointer won't remember to delete itself and does not hold ownership), the normal `reset()` is given a pointer, it does not create a new object by itself.